# How to match multiple strings in awk command

Tags: string, awk, comparison

I want to match print the lines of log file whose 10th field starts with below digits
.I succeeded to print the 10th field only.How to print whole line.
In short I want to compare 10th field with multiple strings at same time

```
tail -f *log|awk -F" " '/Gateway request received for service type Ussd/ {print $10}'|egrep  '254720|254721|254722|254723|254724|254725|254726|254727|254728|254729|254710|254712|254713|254714|254715|254716|254717|254718|254719|254700|254701|254702'.*
```

Comment: edit your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output so we're not guessing what you want.

Comment: The scenario is:I have one of the Telecom operator configured for the service in our application whose numbers starts with above provided series.And I need to print only lines containing these numbers from that operator only.This will help me check number of hits or requests incoming for that operator

Comment: Now the tricky part is the numbers contain 12 digits.I need to make sure that it will only print line containing numbers starting with 6digit series .This will help me check number of hits or requests incoming for that operator

Comment: Second attempt: edit your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output so we're not guessing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -f *log|awk '/Gateway (and rest)/ && $10~/254720|2542...and rest/'
```

should do.

- `-F" "` is not necessary
- grep could (should) be saved
- If the `$10` matches number exactly, you can use `$10>lower-bound && $10<upper-bound` instead of `$10~/regex/`

Comment: Thanks Kent.But I want to match numbers like starting with 254719 or 254700 or.. and ending with any 6 digits .The numbers are 12 digits.I want to match a first 6digits  of the number(string $10) with the given strings

Comment: just add a cap operator in front of the number and dot and dollar operator  at end to match exactly 12 char tail -f *log|awk '/Gateway (and rest)/ && $10~/^254720.{6}$|^2542...and rest/'

Answer (score 0):

perhaps condensing numbers into regex ranges will help

```
$ ... | awk '/Gate... etc./ && $10~/25471[02-9]|25472[0-9]|25470[01]/'
```

or grouping further

```
$ ... | awk '/Gate... etc./ && $10~/2547(1[02-9]|2[0-9]|0[01])/'
```